# Kernel panic - not syncing - Attempted to kill init

Tags: linux, hadoop, linux-kernel, ubuntu-10.04

I am using Linux  2.6.32-33-server  #70-Ubuntu  10.04.3  as Data-Nodes and Name-Node  in my Hadoop cluster, but one of my data node is down since morning. When i restarted that particular system it showed an error 
`"Kernel panic - not syncing - Attempted to kill init!"`

I dont know how to fix it!! Is this a problem with RAM of that system!!

Answer (score 3):

`/sbin/init` is **always** the first process launched on your system. If the binary doesn't exists, the system cannot start. I don't know what happened, but it seems it has been erased from your disk, the easiest way to repair it is to reinstall the entire system. If you did correctly install your system first, you'll just have to reinstall the root partition, and just link your others (/home, /boot, etc...).

If you don't want to do that, first check if the /sbin/init binary exists, you can do that mounting the partition from another one or a LiveCD.

Comment: it is also saying `run -init:/sbin/init : no such file or directory`

Comment: `/sbin/init` is the first process launched on a computer. If it doesn't exists, your system crashes. I think the simplest way for you is to reinstall it...

Answer (score 1):

In all recent systems `initd` is started from `initrd` image. If the kernel can not find it this means that `initrd` is missing or corrupted.